# Can Camunda provides same features as Zeebe for Microservices Orchestration?

Tags: microservices, camunda, zeebe

I have read that Zeebe (https://zeebe.io/) from Camunda is created specifically for Microservices Orchestration. I know there is some difference related to performance.

My question is "Can I achieve the same thing using Camunda what I can do with Zeebe?"

I noticed that Camunda enterprise provides many features that are not provided in the free version or in Zeebe like BPMN deployment, History of previous workflows. I want to get those features for microservice orchestration. My guess is that I will not get if I use Zeebe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are multiple questions in one.

1. Yes, you can do Microservice orchestration with Camunda BPM. As you pointed out correctly, the difference is the architecture of the workflow engine itself, not the use cases you can leverage it for.
2. Yes, there is a Camunda BPM enterprise edition that has features that are not in the community edition, see: https://camunda.com/enterprise/
3. Zeebe will provide the same capabilities eventually. Given that it is relatively young it does not have all features of Camunda BPM on this end. But to relate to your example, Operate can show history instances but is also not free for commercial use. Zeebe is also provided as managed service: https://camunda.com/products/cloud/

Comment: So if I compromise on performance but want more features, then using Camunda Enterprise is suggested? I also need to add User tasks in my workflows where an assigned user will approve or reject the approval task. I guess that can be achieved in Camunda but not in Zeebe.

Comment: Camunda BPM EE is suggested yes. You can actualy handle most performance requirements we see at customers there well (so I would not call it "compromise on performance"). 
We currently implement user tasks in Zeebe, so it will be vailable in Camunda Cloud relatively soon.